# How to solve error 503 Service Unavailable (Ghost)

Tags: ghost-blog

I am running Ghost in development mode on FastComet hosting company. I dont know why but suddenly when i try to access my website I recieve the error

Service Unavailable

```
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

If I do `ghost restart` it says that ghost is turned off, so it’ll turn on and everything comes back to normal. But after some minutes the 503 error comes back.

Does anyone now how can I find out the cause?